# Memory consumption for java web app (300MB too high?)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, memory, velocity

Can I pick your brains about a memory issue?

My java app, which isn't huge (like 14000 LOC) is using about 300MB of memory.  It's running on Tomcat with a MySQL database.  I'm using Hibernate, Spring and Velocity.

It doesn't seem to have any leaks, cause it stabilizes and 300MB, without growing further.  (Also, I done some profiling.)  There's been some concern from my team, however, about the amount of space it's using.  Does this seem high.  Do you have any suggestions for ways to shrink it?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Joe

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to allow us to formulate useful answers. Memory usage is not directly linked to LOC; it depends on what you are doing in those lines. We would have to see the code and/or a good description of functionality to be able to answer intelligently.

Comment: How to shrink it would take some analysis of your code. That doesn't seem ridiculously high, to me at least. My webserver and eclipse together (2 java processes) runs around 1gig of memory. Our web service is a massive number of lines though...

Comment: I would be thrilled with a Spring+Hibernate App that fit into 300MB total memory.... :)  I'm idling at over double that with no load!  think you're doing fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of LOC is not an indicator of how much heap a Java app is going to use; there is no correlation from one to the other.

300MB is not particularly large for a server application that is caching data, but it is somewhat large for an application that is not holding any type of cached or session data (but since this includes the webserver itself, 300MB is generally reasonable).

Answer (score 2):

The amount of code (LOCs) rarely has much impact on the memory usage of your application, after all, it's the variables and objects stored that take most of the memory. To me, 300 megabytes doesn't sound much, but of course it depends on your specific usage scenario:

- How much memory does the production server have?
- How many users are there with this amount of memory used?
- How much does  the memory usage grow per user session?
- How many users are you expecting to be *concurrently* accessing the application in production use?

Based on these, you can do some calculations, eg. is your production environment ready to handle the amount of users you expect, do you need more hardware, do you perhaps need to serialize some data to disk/db etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make any promises, but i don't think you need to worry. We run a couple of web app's at work through Glassfish, using hibernate as well, and each uses about 800-900MB in dev, will often have 2 domain's running each of that size.

Comment: They are all also production applications that have been out for 2+ years

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to reduce your footprint, at least make sure you are using Velocity 1.6 or higher.  1.5 wasted a fair bit of memory.